# How to draw a node wedged between two lines?

Tags: diagrams, nodes, graphs

I am new to this so it is likely this question has been asked before but I wouldn't really know what to search. I want to draw the following

[image: Thing I want to draw]

I really need the $f$ inside the circle, the arrows having directions and the labels $A$ and $B$

Eventually I would like to be able to draw something along the lines of this

[image]

I also need to be able to draw this

[image]

And eventually I want to be able to draw something like this

[image]

Please tell me how I can do this (in particular what packages are needed). I know that pictures in latex is an incredibly laborious process so I do not expect an answer to all of these (although that would be extremely helpful) but rather a point in the right direction as to what packages to use and where I can find a guide that explains how I can use the package because as it stands, I don't really know where to start...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

From showed examples it should be straightforward to construct your other images shown in question. Basis is path decorations used TikZ library `decorations.markings`, with which is drawn arrow on the middle of line. Text at arrows is set by use of  TikZ library `quotes`. Instead of it you can use standard node (not shown in MWE below):

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration = {markings,
                    mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow[thick]{>}}
                                },
                      C/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=1.2em,inner sep=2pt}
                    ]
\draw[postaction={decorate}]  (0,0) -- (2,0);                    
\draw[postaction={decorate}]  (0,1) to["$A$"] (2,1);
\draw[postaction={decorate}]  (0,1) to["$A$"] (2,3);
%
\draw[postaction={decorate}]  (0,-1)  to["$A$"] ++ (2,0) node (a) [C,right] {$f_1$};
\draw[postaction={decorate}]  (a)     to["$B$"] ++ (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```